# Multi step form progress in ios applications

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uianimation

Is there any library for creating multi step form progress in ios applications similar below image

[image]

Comment: you got any success with this?

Comment: @BhavikKama No, client refreshed this screen with new design

Comment: @BhavikKama any progress with this???

Comment: nope not yet have any luck

Answer (score 1):

I may be too late to answer this question but I found just what you're looking for:

https://github.com/yenbekbay/AYStepperView

It's written in Objective-C.

P.S. I have not tested it yet but it looks pretty cool.

Comment: can you suggest one for swift with carthage support?